# MySQL football stats in one query

Tags: mysql

I have a table "game" that looks like this:

TABLE GAME:

```
id (int)
home_team (varchar)
away_team (varchar)
home_goals (int)
away_goals (int)
```

For a particular match I need to fetch the following:

For the home team:

```
home wins
home tie
home loss
home scored
home conceded
```

As I need to know also the total number of all the entities above (wins, loss, scored etc) then I basically need the same as above, but when the team plays away, so:

```
away wins
away tie
away loss
away scored
away conceded
```

For the away team:

```
away wins
away tie
away loss
away scored
away conceded
```

As I need to know also the total number of all the entities above (wins, loss, scored etc) then I basically need the same as above, but when the team plays at home, so:

```
home wins
home tie
home loss
home scored
home conceded
```

The best would be to get all this in one query. Im afraid it could be difficult. So I can imagine I need to have multipla queries.
At the moment I have 2 queries just to get data for the team that plays at home:

```
select
count(case when home_goals > away_goals then 1 else null end) as state_win
,count(case when home_goals < away_goals then 1 else null end) as state_loss
,count(case when home_goals = away_goals then 1 else null end) as state_tie
,sum(home_goals) as state_scored
,sum(away_goals) as state_conceded
from
game 
where 
home_team = 'chelsea'

select
count(case when home_goals < away_goals then 1 else null end) as other_win
,count(case when home_goals > away_goals then 1 else null end) as other_loss
,count(case when home_goals = away_goals then 1 else null end) as other_tie
,sum(away_goals) as other_scored
,sum(home_goals) as other_conceded
from
game 
where 
away_team = 'chelsea'
```

My plan is to sum stats from query 1 with query 2 in order to get the total.
Is there a way to do this query only once? I tried with union but IM not sure its the right way to go.

Comment: This question has certainly been asked and answered before.

Comment: Is it possible to store extra info in the DB? Because it seems to be like the simplest solution would just be to store the home team points (3, 1 or 0) for each game, making for much faster and simpler SELECTs.

Comment: See for instance http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=804

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try union to combine home and away games stats in one query. Simple union would not work because of the different names/semantics of columns.

```
select
'home' as place
,count(case when home_goals > away_goals then 1 else null end) as win
,count(case when home_goals < away_goals then 1 else null end) as loss
,count(case when home_goals = away_goals then 1 else null end) as tie
,sum(home_goals) as scored
,sum(away_goals) as conceded
from
game 
where 
home_team = 'chelsea'
union
select
'away' as place
,count(case when home_goals < away_goals then 1 else null end) as win
,count(case when home_goals > away_goals then 1 else null end) as loss
,count(case when home_goals = away_goals then 1 else null end) as tie
,sum(away_goals) as scored
,sum(home_goals) as conceded
from
game 
where 
away_team = 'chelsea'
```

Ant use this long query to get the result in the exact format you specified:

```
select 
a.win as state_win
,a.loss as state_loss
,a.tie as state_tie
,a.scored as state_scored
,a.conceded as state_conceded
,h.win as other_win
,h.loss as other_loss
,h.tie as other_tie
,h.scored as other_scored
,h.conceded as other_conceded
from 
(select
'home' as place
,count(case when home_goals > away_goals then 1 else null end) as win
,count(case when home_goals < away_goals then 1 else null end) as loss
,count(case when home_goals = away_goals then 1 else null end) as tie
,sum(home_goals) as scored
,sum(away_goals) as conceded
from
game 
where 
home_team = 'chelsea'
union
select
'away' as place
,count(case when home_goals < away_goals then 1 else null end) as win
,count(case when home_goals > away_goals then 1 else null end) as loss
,count(case when home_goals = away_goals then 1 else null end) as tie
,sum(away_goals) as scored
,sum(home_goals) as conceded
from
game 
where 
away_team = 'chelsea') h,
(select
'home' as place
,count(case when home_goals > away_goals then 1 else null end) as win
,count(case when home_goals < away_goals then 1 else null end) as loss
,count(case when home_goals = away_goals then 1 else null end) as tie
,sum(home_goals) as scored
,sum(away_goals) as conceded
from
game 
where 
home_team = 'chelsea'
union
select
'away' as place
,count(case when home_goals < away_goals then 1 else null end) as win
,count(case when home_goals > away_goals then 1 else null end) as loss
,count(case when home_goals = away_goals then 1 else null end) as tie
,sum(away_goals) as scored
,sum(home_goals) as conceded
from
game 
where 
away_team = 'chelsea') a
where h.place='home' and a.place='away'
```

Comment: It works. Thank you. However, the results are inverted. Im trying to debug. For example it says chelsea won 0 at home and 1 away (but is actually is 1 win at home and 0 win away).

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry. Switch a.place and h.place in the last row.